# How to calculate container grid sizes including gutter, column and outside space in foundation 6 large screen sizes?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, grid-layout

I am trying to create an accurate Photoshop grid. I understand that foundation is responsive and that pixel sizes will vary according to the resize. However, I would like to design images and containers that will precisely expand based on a precise proportion that I started with. For that, I would like to understand how the browser actually builds these columns and gutters and what are the sizes assigned to each space, including incomplete columns and outside space.

[image]

I started with a 1025 resolution (large screen breakpoint) and I tried to create a grid by using http://gridcalculator.dk/#/1024/12/30/30

I imagined that at the 1025 size the have these proportions, but I don't know:

Question 1- How many gutters foundation creates? are there external gutters or margins automatically added to the end of the grid?

Question 2- Are the column sizes always the same or one of them become a different size in weird sizes?

Question 3- What is the size of the external area?

Then I tried to find out some example in code pen and I noticed the following:
[image]

A-There are no visible gutters when rendered in the browser, at least in this example
B-It seems that the column space stays the same width (1200) when stretching from a 1200 horizontal screen to 2000 (my monitor), so it's always a fixed 1200 width that the grid takes space, but that changed when it shrinks.

In that case, it makes me think that the supposedly the actual grid size at large screen is 1200, with these configurations:

with external gutter/margin

[image: with external gutter/margin]

without external gutter/margin

[image: without external gutter/margin]

However that is still unclear for me because when rendered on code pen it doesn't show the gutter, are they collapse for some reason on those sizes?